# hibernate sql generation for select

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have 2 entitys 1 named natureza and another named subnatureza

```
@Entity(name = "natureza")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Natureza extends AbstractEntity{
    String nome;    
    @JoinColumn(name="natureza_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<SubNatureza> subNaturezas;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_natureza")
public class SubNatureza extends AbstractEntity{
    private String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

In my natureza table I have 5 rows and in subnatureza 10 (2 for each natureza)
So when I run a NaturezaRepository.findAll(); the hibernate show in console one select in subnatureza for each natureza (in my case 5 selects)

It`s correctly? because if in my db I only run a:

Select * from natureza n JOIN sub_natureza s ON n.id = s.natureza_id once

tks

Answer (score 1):

Well in Hibernate when you try `NaturezaRepository.findAll();` you are actually trying

```
Select * from natureza n
```

and when you run this is Mysql as native query it will give you 5 record which is what Hibernate is also doing. So to answer your question is this correct? Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

> NaturezaRepository.findAll(); the hibernate show in console one select in subnatureza for each natureza (in my case 5 selects)

**So in total you are seeing 6 queries and this is a classic n+ 1 problem.**

You can use [@EntityGraph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) on the `findAll` method on `NaturezaRepository`. Create `findAll()` method if one doesn't already exist in your `NaturezaRepository`.

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"subNaturezas"})
Page<Natureza> findAll()
```

The other option is using [@Query(Your JPQL join query)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) on top of `findAll` method.